# iPhone : Parse XML file with attribute

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing

i want to parse the XML file. i am enable to parse simple XML file. but there are little complex XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Level>
<p id='327'>
   <Item>
      <Id>5877</Id>
      <Type>0</Type>
      <Icon>---</Icon>
      <Title>Btn1Item1</Title>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Id>5925</Id>
      <Type>0</Type>
      <Icon>---</Icon>
      <Title>Btn1Item4</Title>
   </Item>
</p>
</Level>
```

Here i want to get the value of `<p>` tag (i mean i want to get the value of attribute id which is 327)
Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to find your "id" value in XML parsing method,

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"p"])
    {

        int idValue = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];

        NSLog(@"Reading id value :%d", idValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: in my case i have declared int *count in .h file and used it as count = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"count"] intValue]; in .m file but it gives a warning " warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast "

Comment: Y you wrote int * count? It should be int count; only.

Answer (score 0):

In your `(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict`method, the `attributeDict` argument contains all the attributes. For example, to access the 'id' attribute, simply call `[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"]`.