# Parsing XML, details and attributes, iphone

Tags: iphone, xml

I'm not sure about parsing an xml with attributes.  have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519433/iphone-parse-xml-file-with-attribute)
 But it shows to get an attribute of intValue. But i need to get the attributes of string type,How to do that?? Images of xml and the relevant portions are given in the following links

Click [here for xml](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2c59086d30.jpg) and [here for required data](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7cca3bd1e5.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519433/iphone-parse-xml-file-with-attribute/1519494#1519494) to the linked question should work for you as well.  The contents of attributeDict are already NStrings.  All that is going on extra in the linked answer that they are calling the intValue method on the returned NSString to parse that string into an int.  In your case, you don't need this little bit of an extra step.  If you just do this:

```
NSString * stringValue = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"attribute"];
```

you'll have the value of the attribute called "attribute" in a string.