# parsing xml data iphone

Tags: iphone, xml

In my application i need to parse the xml data which looks like below

```
<INLINE>
<IMG IMGSRC="LINK_0_65.png" ALT="heading" URL="" FNAME="Arial" FSIZE="1" TEXT-ALIGN="center" LINE-HEIGHT="20px" LINKID="12571" ENTITYID="0" ENTITYNAME="" ENTITYTYPE="" CONTROLTYPE="" ISPERSONALIZE="False" MAXLENGTH="0" ISMULTILINE="False" ISMANDATORY="False" VALUES="" BUTTONTEXT="" BGIMAGE="" COLSPAN="8" STARTDATE="07/10/2010" ENDDATE="07/10/2030" LINKTEXT="خدمات ديني يقيني" NOOFARTICLES="0" ISABSTRACT="False" CUSTOMCONTROLID="" WSDLURL="" WEBMETHODNAME="" PARAMNAMES="" PARAMVALUES="" NUMOFCOLOUMNS="9" NUMOFROWS="20">RamadanPortal</IMG>
</INLINE>
```

Then my question how to get the individual elements in the node inline into array for eg: `IMGSRC(IMGSRC="LINK_0_65.png"),ALT,FNAME(FNAME="Arial)` and so on...
Please help me ..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i simply used nsxmlparser for getting the individual elements like imgsrc,alt so on...

below are the useful urls for that
nsxml parser basics
[nsxml parser basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705588/nsxmlparser-example)

[parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040028/parsing-xml-details-and-attributes-iphone)