# How to parse the xml file which include attributes in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I have an the following xml file. I want to parse the elements `current_date_time`, `condition`, `humidity`, `icon`, `wind_condition`, `low`, `high`. All these elements include attributes. I know how to parse a simple xml file. But all these elements contains attribute values.

So how would I parse this xml file?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
    <xml_api_reply version="1">
        <weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
            <forecast_information>
                <city data="" /> 
                <postal_code data="" /> 
                <latitude_e6 data="50500000" /> 
                <longitude_e6 data="30500000" /> 
                <forecast_date data="2011-05-27" /> 
                <current_date_time data="2011-05-27 04:30:00 +0000" /> 
                <unit_system data="US" /> 
            </forecast_information>
            <current_conditions>
                <condition data="Clear" /> 
                <temp_f data="57" /> 
                <temp_c data="14" /> 
                <humidity data="Humidity: 59%" /> 
                <icon data="http://g0.gstatic.com/images/icons/onebox/weather_sunny-40.gif" /> 
                <wind_condition data="Wind: S at 9 mph" /> 
            </current_conditions>
            <forecast_conditions>
                <day_of_week data="Fri" /> 
                <low data="54" /> 
                <high data="72" /> 
                <icon data="http://g0.gstatic.com/images/icons/onebox/weather_partlycloudy-40.gif" /> 
                <condition data="Mostly Sunny" /> 
            </forecast_conditions>
            <forecast_conditions>
                <day_of_week data="Sat" /> 
                <low data="52" /> 
                <high data="79" /> 
                <icon data="http://g0.gstatic.com/images/icons/onebox/weather_partlycloudy-40.gif" /> 
                <condition data="Mostly Sunny" /> 
            </forecast_conditions>
            <forecast_conditions>
                <day_of_week data="Sun" /> 
                <low data="55" /> 
                <high data="84" /> 
                <icon data="http://g0.gstatic.com/images/icons/onebox/weather_partlycloudy-40.gif" /> 
                <condition data="Mostly Sunny" /> 
            </forecast_conditions>
            <forecast_conditions>
                <day_of_week data="Mon" /> 
                <low data="63" /> 
                <high data="84" /> 
                <icon data="http://g0.gstatic.com/images/icons/onebox/weather_partlycloudy-40.gif" /> 
                <condition data="Mostly Sunny" /> 
            </forecast_conditions>
        </weather>
    </xml_api_reply>


    Please help me in solving this problem. Thanks. Can anybody provide me any sample code on this?


i have done this code to parse the above xml file but my problem is checks only the first xml tag i.e the root element xml_ap_reply for every checking

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString*) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString*)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict
{


if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"xml_api_reply"])
    {
        mWeather = [[TWeatherElement alloc]init];


    }

     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"current_date_time"])
    {
         NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.mParserArray=temp;
        [temp release];


         [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];

    }

     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"condition"])
    {
        NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.mParserArray=temp;
        [temp release];


        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];

    }

     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"humidity"])
    {
        NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.mParserArray=temp;
        [temp release];


        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];

    }

     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"icon"])
    {
        NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.mParserArray=temp;
        [temp release];


        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];

    }   
     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"wind_condition"])
    {
        NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.mParserArray=temp;
        [temp release];


        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];

    }

     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"low"])
    {
        NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.mParserArray=temp;
        [temp release];


        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];

    }

     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"high"])
    {
        NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.mParserArray=temp;
        [temp release];


        [mParserArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];

    }
```

please help me in solving this problem.Thanks

Comment: Here is a good tutorial that shows XML parsing using GDataXMLParser. [how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519433/iphone-parse-xml-file-with-attribute or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040028/parsing-xml-details-and-attributes-iphone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

suppose  `<postal_code data="" />` 
and you want data value so  what you have to do is:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{         

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"postal_code"])
    {
        NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.registrationResponseArray = temp;
        [temp release];

        [registrationResponseArray addObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]];  
    }
}
```

`[attributeDict valueForKey:@"data"]` will give you the attribute value, then you can add anywhere (whatever structure you are using).

Comment: @Rocky you have to mention this answer is to explain you how to extract attibutes.

Comment: i have done this code but it always checks the root element for ever tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DDXML parser and simply use this

```
[[Element attributeForName:@"url"] stringValue];
```

where attributeForName is a function available to you.
This(DDXML) is a realy nice libxml parser.